# How to do double calculation in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure if my question title is meaningful or not. I need to calculate some data.

I only have Sales1 and Sales2 details.

I am stuck at SQL calculation. TotalSales is Sales1 + Sales2.. SST = TotalSales * 6% and GrandTotal is TotalSales + SST.

I need output something like this:

Oh and Sales1 and Sales2 also generate from SUM(amount) from other fields. So, it's calculation over other calculation

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|  Sales1  |  Sales2  |     TotalSales     | SST      | GrandTotal  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|    10.00 |   20.00  |   30.00            |     1.80 |     31.80   |
|    50.00 |   75.90  |  125.90            |    7.554 |    133.454  |
|    20.10 |   55.50  |   75.60            |    4.536 |     80.136  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to generate the SQL? Something like this seems not working.. How to use back TotalSales & SST?

```
Select sum(amount1) Sales1, 
       sum(amount2) Sales2, 
       (Sales1 + Sales2) TotalSales, 
       ((Sales1 + Sales2) * 6/100) SST, 
       ((Sales1 + Sales2) + ((Sales1 + Sales2) * 6/100)) GrandTotal 
from sales_tbl;
```

Comment: Can you post the output of your SQL? That'll give some clues as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: It says incorrect syntax

Comment: The _syntax_ is fine, but the query is semantically wrong. In a select list, you can't reference column aliases from the same select list. I.e. sales1 and sales2 can't be used for further calculations.

Comment: @jarlh depends on rdbms

Comment: @Gnudiff, perhaps, but only <sql> is tagged, which means ANSI SQL.

Comment: Please also add what SQL server is this. Mssql,MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Comment: its in SQL server management studio.. was trying the sql 1st before move into the codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the first step query up as a derived table, to calculate sales1 and sales2. Then do the rest of the calculations on its result:

```
select sales1, sales2,
       (Sales1 + Sales2) TotalSales, 
       ((Sales1 + Sales2) * 6/100) SST, 
       ((Sales1 + Sales2) + ((Sales1 + Sales2) * 6/100)) GrandTotal 
from
(
    select sum(amount1) Sales1, sum(amount2) Sales2
    from sales_tbl
) dt
```

Comment: I have small problem.. The GrandTotal.. it is auto rounding to 2 decimal point.. how to make it at least 4 decimal point? because SST value.. i got it correct up to 3 decimal point..

Comment: @Julie, try `* 6.0`. Any difference? BTW, column amount1 and amount2 data types?

Comment: no.. still round up to 2 decimal.. Other option is to round up SST value to 2 decimal as well..  i try to use str(GrandTotal,12,4).. got syntax error .. huhu

Comment: cast(column as decimal(15,5)) something?

Comment: Invalid syntax :/

Comment: i did something like this... but its like.. sooo complicated

`select sales1 Sale1, sales2 Sale2, TotalSales, str(SST,15,5) SST, str(GrandTotal,15,5) GrandTotal 
from (select sales1, sales2,
       (Sales1 + Sales2) TotalSales, 
       ((Sales1 + Sales2) * 6/100) SST, 
       ((Sales1 + Sales2) + ((Sales1 + Sales2) * 6/100)) GrandTotal 
      from
       (
       select sum(amount1) Sales1, sum(amount2) Sales2
       from sales_tbl
        ) dt )
) aa`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've never used SQL Server, so it looks like you know this part better than me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sub-query. Try something like:

```
SELECT subquery.Sales1
      ,subquery.Sales2
      ,(subquery.Sales1 + subquery.Sales2) TotalSales
      ,((subquery.Sales1 + subquery.Sales2) * 6 / 100) SST
      ,((subquerySales1 + subquery,Sales2) + ((subquery,Sales1 + subquery,Sales2) * 6 / 100)) GrandTotal
FROM (
       SELECT sum(amount1) Sales1
             ,sum(amount2) Sales2
       FROM sales_tbl
    ) subquery
```

Comment: Yes.. works now.. ~big smile on my face~.. Thank you !

Comment: @Julie glad I made you smile!!

Comment: I have small problem.. The GrandTotal.. it is auto rounding to 2 decimal point.. how to make it at least 4 decimal point? because SST value.. i got it correct up to 3 decimal point